# Serve 404 error, if typing not exact URL

Tags: apache, 404

At the moment, when I type:

```
xyz.lo/abc.php/123
```

in my webbrowser, Apache serves the same page if I were typing

```
xyz.lo/abc.php
```

Unfortunatelly relative links present in HTML won't work with the first version. How do I make Apache serve 404 error, if I type not exact URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable PATH_INFO feature:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

([doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo))